# Shouldn't Building An Association Complete The Inverse Relationship?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I was surprised to find that, given:

```
class Foo
  has_many :bars
  attr_accessible :baz
end
class Bar
  belongs_to :foo, inverse_of: :foo
end
```

Then doing this:

```
new_bar = foo.bars.build params
puts new_bar.foo.baz
```

Issues a call to the database to fetch foo.  Whaaa?

You can prevent it by completing the inverse relation yourself:

```
new_bar.foo = foo
```

Am I doing something wrong? Is there any good reason that `#build`, knowing everything about both sides of the relation, should not compelte it?